Reference to $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \chi_d(n)q^\frac{n^2}{ d} , \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \chi_{d}(n)\frac{n}{\sqrt{|d|} } q^\frac{n^2}{ |d|}$
We write
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{d}(n)q^\frac{n^2}{|d|} ,
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{d}(n)\frac{n}{\sqrt{|d|} } q^\frac{n^2}{|d|}
$$
where $d\in\mathbb{Z}^*$ and $\chi_d(n)=
\left(\frac{d}{n}\right),\chi_d(0)=0$, $(\frac{m}n)$ denotes Kronecker symbol. The elliptic nome $q=e^{-\pi K^\prime/K}$ is used here. For some specific $d$, the result is quite neat, for it avoids theta functions with powered arguments(like $\vartheta_3(q^3)$). For example, when $D$ a discriminant of imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}),d<0$, I have experimentally obtained the following results:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{-4}(n)\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) q^\frac{n^2}{ 4}
 & = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi} }  \right )^3
\cdot\frac{1}{2}k^{1/2}\left ( 1-k^2\right )^{1/4},\\
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{-8}(n)\left(\frac{n}{2\sqrt{2} }\right) q^\frac{n^2}{ 8}
&  = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi} }  \right )^3
\cdot\frac{1}{2}k^{1/4}\left ( 1-k^2\right )^{1/8},\\
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{-3}(n)\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{3} }\right) q^\frac{n^2}{ 3}
&  = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi} }  \right )^3
\cdot\frac{2^{-1/3}}{\sqrt{3} }k^{2/3}\left ( 1-k^2\right )^{1/3},\\
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
\chi_{-24}(n)\left(\frac{n}{2\sqrt{6} }\right) q^\frac{n^2}{ 24}
 & = \left ( \sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi} }  \right )^3
\cdot\frac{2^{-2/3}}{\sqrt{3} }k^{1/12}\left ( 1-k^2\right )^{1/24}.
\end{align}
$$
The $k^a(1-k^2)^b$ pattern fails to occur when $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5}),d=-20$. Are there any theoretical reasons for the neat appearance of these series and whether there exist other $d$ satisfying the pattern? Thanks for enlightening me.
